# Insert data when not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have that diagram. UserId for both table are same (take it as foreign key).
How can which `UserId` doesn't exists in `UserAdditioStamp` table and then insert these data in `UserAdditioStamp` table.

[image]

```
SELECT 
    min(ev.UserId) as UserId, ev.Value, 
    min(uas.UserId) as AdditionUserId, 
    max(uas.[TimeStamp]) as AdditionTimestamp, 
    count(ev.UserId) as [Registrations]
FROM 
    EventLog ev
LEFT JOIN
    UserAdditionStamp uas ON ev.UserId = uas.UserId
WHERE 
    uas.UserId IS NULL
    AND EventTypeId = 3 
    AND Value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    ev.Value
ORDER BY
    UserId
```

I'm trying that for select but it gives wrong result about registrations count (there should be 2 registrations for UserId = 10, 2 for 13 etc.)

```
UserId AdditionUserId AdditionTimestamp [Registrations]
3       NULL                NULL            1
10      NULL                NULL            1
10      NULL                NULL            1
13      NULL                NULL            1
13      NULL                NULL            1
```

and then I want to insert these data in `UserAdditioStamp` table. How is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to insert UserId, and TimeStamp from EventLog to UserAdditionStamp table if UserId is not exist in UserAdditionStamp?

Or 

TimeStamp value is different from EventLog table?

Comment: yeah I want to insert UserId, and TimeStamp from EventLog to UserAdditionStamp table if UserId is not exist in UserAdditionStamp @DMayuri

Comment: please see my answer that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO UserAdditionStamp 
SELECT e.UserId, e.TimeStamp 
FROM EventLog e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserId FROM UserAdditionStamp WHERE UserId = e.UserId)
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO UserAdditionStamp 
SELECT e.UserId, e.TimeStamp 
FROM EventLog e 
WHERE e.UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM UserAdditionStamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
insert into UserAdditionStamp ( UserId, TimeStamp )
select UserId, TimeStamp 
from EventLog 
where (userId not in ( select UserId from UserAdditionStamp ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. You talk about to insert data and then you talk about a group by select issue. If the core of your question is

> I want to insert UserId, and TimeStamp from EventLog to UserAdditionStamp table if UserId is not exist in UserAdditionStamp

then a readable way is to user [merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), an approach:

```
; WITH E as 
( select  e.UserId, MAX( e.TimeStamp  ) as TimeStamp
FROM EventLog e
GROUP BY  e.UserId
)
MERGE UserAdditionStamp AS TARGET
USING E as SOURCE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (UserId, TimeStamp )
    VALUES (SOURCE.UserId, SOURCE.TimeStamp)
END;
```

But according [MS performance tip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

> **Performance Tip**: The conditional behavior described for the MERGE statement works best when the two tables have a complex mixture of matching characteristics. For example, inserting a row if it does not exist, or updating the row if it does match. When simply updating one table based on the rows of another table, improved performance and scalability can be achieved with basic INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.

you will get more performance using a simple insert:

```
INSERT UserAdditionStamp (UserId, TimeStamp )
SELECT e.UserId, MAX( e.TimeStamp  ) as TimeStamp
FROM EventLog e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM UserAdditionStamp A2
                  WHERE A2.UserId = e.UserId)
GROUP BY  e.UserId
;
```

Comment: When I execute your code it says Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table..

Comment: `where ... and e.UserId is not null`